# How do I move a div over to the right side of the screen but have the text align of the left border of the div?

Tags: css, html

here's my code:

```
<div id="Notify" style="clear:both;">
    <div style="text-align:right;">
        <div style="text-align:left;">
            Send Table to Standards By Email. (everything below is a placeholder)
            <br /><br />
            Saved at: @DateTime.Now.ToString()
            <br />  
            Saved by: 107
            <br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Send Email" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div id="PTable">
    Products Table Placeholder
</div>
```

When I try this, everything is aligned to the left. If I use float:right, then PTable and Notify are side by side. As opposed to PTable being below Notify.

What I would like is: Notify on top and all the text in its inner div aligned on the left border of the inner div. PTable under Notify aligned how the browser sees fit.

Comment: I've brushed up your code. Please edit to what you want and add to your post so others can help you better: http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/E5umG/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to use both `float: right` and then `text-align: left` on `div#Notify` to achieve this effect. Further, to make sure PTable does not show up beside Notify, use `clear: both`.

```
#Notify, #PTable {
    clear: both;
}

#Notify {
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SDDG2/2/

Comment: Yeah, he's right. What you have is 99% correct :) However, PTable should not float:right. Notify and PTable should however clear:both.

Comment: My bad, I misread the question. The answer should be correct now. Hope I helped!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work!

```
<div id="Notify" style="clear:both;">
    <div style="float:right;">
        <div style="text-align:left;">
            Send Table to Standards By Email. (everything below is a placeholder)
            <br /><br />
            Saved at: @DateTime.Now.ToString()
            <br />  
            Saved by: 107
            <br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Send Email" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div id="PTable" style="clear:both;">
    Products Table Placeholder
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you JSW789 and everyone else to answered!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a fixed width for the Notify div, this will ensure that PTable is not beside it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would that be best practice in HTML5 and CSS 2/3?

Answer (score 0):

You can move div upper side of div
for ex:-

$("#parent").prepend($("#outer"));